# Oracle Forms and Reports - Which JAR file contains java.reports.server.Security?

Tags: java, forms, oracle, report

I am currently attempting to build a JAR file which interfaces with Oracle Reports; I need to know which JAR file contains `java.reports.server.Security` in order to fix a compilation issue and my google-fu skills have thus far proven inadequate.  Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is wondering about the answer to this; I found the JAR files required for reports API dependency resolution.

They are as follows:

$ORACLE_HOME/jlib/zrclient.jar

-AND-

$ORACLE_HOME/reports/jlib/rwrun.jar

I hope this helps if anyone else becomes as stuck as I was...